# where can I find simple Lego ideas

Tags: ideas

I have just acquired a bunch of bricks and specialized bricks. Where could I get a lot of ideas?

Anything to do with a city would be good. I have already tried the LEGO club.

Comment: just found out about lego ideas book expensive

Comment: You might consider checking out the LEGO Adventure Book. There are two volumes available now, and they are full of interesting ideas (I wrote a review on the first one here: http://thebrickblogger.com/2012/12/lego-book-review-the-lego-adventure-book/.) They are not only City related, but many of them are. Also, if you like LEGO's own designs, you can download instruction books on LEGO's website and use those for inspiration. They are available here: http://service.lego.com/en-us/buildinginstructions/.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty vague question, but here are some general resources on city building:

[Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/home) has a large selection of MOCs. Browse through it and see if you can find something fun there.

You can look through all of the official City sets. [Brickset is a good place for that.](http://brickset.com/sets/theme-City)

Twinlug has a fun [Micropolis standard](http://twinlug.com/micropolis-micro-city-standard/) you can use to build a large layout together with other fans.

When you get serious, you might want to get into the [modular buildings](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Modular_Buildings) - it has become a pretty common standard to build for as well.

Hopefully that gives you a start.